# Javascript document.domain

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access a work server for use with an application called Spotfire.  My colleague who passed me this is now off for a couple of weeks, and I have an issue with what he advised me.

Effectively when I run my web app via localhost, I get an error saying that I cannot access my work server.  My colleague had said that I need to set document.domain to our work domain, but when I do this as such:

```
document.domain = "workdomain.net";
```

I get an error saying that it is an invalid argument.  Any idea how to get around this?

Thanks,

Darren.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

"A script can set the value of document.domain to a **subset** of the **current** domain. If it does so, the shorter domain is used for subsequent origin checks."

The reason you're getting the javascript error is because you're trying to set the document.domain to a completely different domain than your current one ("localhost").

Rather than this, I suggest you add an entry to your host file...

```
127.0.0.1 local.workdomain.net
```

...and then navigate to local.workdomain.net

Comment: Don't you mean "more lenient?"