# Touch location misinterpreted on iPad when rescaling an iframe showing a kineticjs canvas

Tags: html, ipad, iframe, transform, kineticjs

I am building a widget using [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com) (which is fantastic). It allows the user to drag images around in a canvas.

I can view and use the widget inside an `iframe`: this works perfectly on all the browsers and devices I have tried.

I can even scale that `iframe` so the page is responsive. Following [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe), I have added the `css`:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    iframe {
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.85);
        -o-transform: scale(0.85);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.85);
    }
}
```

This works well on my Mac.

But on an iPad, although the `iframe` appears properly scaled, when you try to drag elements around, it seems to think they are in their unscaled positions.

Is there a way I can get this to work on the iPad too? Or do I need to rethink my design (in which case, what design should I use)?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to scale you canvas content as well?

Comment: I was thinking of doing that next, but it will take some work as I use absolute positions and image sizes on the canvas.  I could make the canvas scale to its container size, and then just size the iframe to what i want (and not use the transform css above). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly, but you can keep your absolute positions, just use the `stage.scale()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @irie11's suggestion, I have now implemented this.  In the interests of posterity, here is my full approach.

I added some javascript to rescale the canvas when the window changes size:

```
function scaleCanvasToContainer() {
  var container_width = $("#my-containers-parent-id").width();
  var scale = 1.0;
  if (container_width<target_width) {
    scale = container_width/target_width;
  }
  $("#my-container-id").css("max-height",scale*target_height+"px");
  stage.setScale(scale,scale);
  stage.setWidth(scale*target_width);
  stage.setHeight(scale*target_height);
  stage.draw();
  drawLines();
}
window.onresize = function(event) {
  scaleCanvasToContainer();
}
...
scaleCanvasToContainer();
```

Note the above also resizes the canvas (i.e. changes its width and height), and for good measure sets the maximum height through css too.

I discovered that when you use `context.moveTo()` these coordinates are not scaled, so I had to manually scale them, e.g.

```
function drawLines() {
  var canvas = layer.getCanvas();
  var context = canvas.getContext();
  var scaleX = stage.getScaleX();
  var scaleY = stage.getScaleY();
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(targetX*scaleX,targetY*scaleY);
  ...
}
```

I changed the css on my canvas a little to include:

```
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

So far, we have scaled the content to the size of the containing iframe.  However, we also need to make that iframe have the right size.

So I added some javascript to the calling page:

```
<script>
  function scaleIFrame() {
    var target_width = 850;
    var container_width = $("#iframe-parent").width();
    var width = target_width;
    if (container_width<target_width) {
      width = container_width;
    }
    $("#iframe-parent iframe").css("width",width+"px");
  }
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    scaleIFrame();
  }
  scaleIFrame();
</script>
```

This leaves me with just one problem: setting the height of the iframe. In theory I should be able to access the height of the contents of the iframe using something like this (see this [link](http://www.daveoncode.com/2009/06/12/adapting-iframe-height-to-its-content-with-2-lines-of-javascript/)):

```
var iframe = $("iframe");
var iframe_internal = iframe.contents().find("#my-content");
iframe.css("height",iframe_internal.style.height+"px");
```

This requires the two sites involved to be at the same domain; if they are on the same top-level domain you can still do it if you include a `document.domain` tag in both the iframe content and the calling page (see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898253/javascript-document-domain)). You may also want to give your localhost the domain name you are using, so that you can test it (see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442081/when-using-sub-domains-for-a-django-site-how-can-you-share-django-logins-across)) - I just added a new line to my /etc/hosts file: '127.0.0.1   local.example.com'.

I followed this last process (my two sites have the same top-level domain), but when I print out the `iframe_internal` variable it is an object with zero length, so something is going wrong here.

Still, I am very happy to have got this far.  It works on the iPad and all browsers I have tested.